# OpenCV 3.0 Machine Learning TrainData::loadFromCSV

Tags: c++, machine-learning, opencv3.0

I am trying to implement Boosting machine learning algorithm using OpenCV 3.0. To train the classifier, I am using TrainData class of opencv. In this class, there is a function loadFromCSV which loads the data from a .csv file. In this, there is a parameter **varTypeSpec**, which according to the documentation is **optional**. But it throws an assertion:

> in opencv-source-directory/modules/ml/src/data.cpp:600:
>   error: (-215) (!varTypesSet && vtypes[i] == rowtypes[i]) || (varTypesSet && (vtypes[i] == rowtypes[i] || rowtypes[i] == VAR_ORDERED)) in function loadCSV

In opencv-source-directory/modules/ml/src/data.cpp, there is a for loop and it contains only this assertion. [Here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/src/data.cpp) is the code

```
 for( i = 0; i < nvars; i++ )
 {
    CV_Assert( (!varTypesSet && vtypes[i] == rowtypes[i]) ||
               (varTypesSet && (vtypes[i] == rowtypes[i] || rowtypes[i] == VAR_ORDERED)) );
 }
```

Is it a bug? Could anyone please tell me a way around? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Looking at the code, it appears that if varTypeSpec is not specified, then the first row of data is used to deduce the expected row types for the rest of the data.  So this assertion will also fail if there is any inconsistencies in the row types of the .csv file.  I would recommend carefully examining that file for any such inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea. I am using supervised learning. So in the .csv file I have used first column for the output (Positive(P), Negative(N)) and other columns for input (keypoint descriptors). Maybe due to this there are inconsistencies. I'll update the file. Thanks again!!